# How to show that a languge is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

How can I show that this language is not regular?

$$
    L = \{a^n (ca)^m b^{n+1} \mid m \ge 0 , n \ge 0 \}
$$

This is my attempted solution:

Assuming the pumping number to be *$p$* and making *$m=0$*

the language reduces to $a^p b^{p+1}$ so  $s=a^p b^{p+1}$

let $s=xyz$ where $y$ is not $\epsilon \\$

$y=a^k$; $0 \lt k<=p$

$x=a^q$; $0 \lt= q \lt p$

$z=a^{p-k-q}b^{n+1}$

so with this definitions, $xyyz$ cannot be part of the language since this would be written as

$xyyz$=$a^qa^ka^ka^{p-k-q}b^{p+1}$ = $a^{k+p}b^{p+1}$ which means there is always an extra $a$ which is not in the original language.

Is this approach correct ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate of our generic question on the subject. If you've tried the classic methods (at least the pumping lemma) and failed, show us what you've done so far and we can guide you further.

Comment: Your solution is correct.